# Where is the [Rollback] Feature in Nunit?

Tags: asp.net, nunit

I want to use the role back feature yet when I write the tag it seems to not exists.

I am using nunit 2.5.0

I just used the nunit.framework.dll

Do I need to add some other .dll in?

Also does anyone know how I actually get nunit to connect to a sql sever database in an asp.net application?

I am not sure where to put my connection string.

Comment: See this question for an alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321180/how-do-i-test-database-related-code-with-nunit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no such attribute in 2.5 (see [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=attributes&r=2.5) for a list of supported attributes). Read [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/06/10/4580.aspx) for the DIY approach.

Comment: Hmm I guess i miss read it or something I thought I read that it did have it.

Comment: @chobo2 - It is documented as functionality that exists in Roy Osherove's "The Art of Unit Testing" (B.4.2)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use [XTUnit or NUnitX](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2004/07/12/180189.aspx), not plain NUnit.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but I thought I'd share for future reference.

As far as I can tell, there isn't a native `[Rollback]` attribute. However, you can write your own pretty easily:

[This blog post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/04/rollback-attribute-for-nunit-and-entity-framework/) shows how to write a custom rollback attribute for NUnit, so that you can write
`[Test, Rollback]` at the beginning of each test (or at the beginning of the TestFixture if you prefer).

It's fairly straightforward, and it uses `System.Transaction.TransactionScope()` to do the meat of it.

Of course, you can always just use TransactionScope() in your SetUp/TearDown to accomplish the same thing, see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321180/how-do-i-test-database-related-code-with-nunit).