# Is it possible to restore a database at the end of every NUnit test?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, ui-automation

I'm writing a few UI automation test scripts using C#, NUnit and Selenium WebDriver. I would like to know if it's possible to restore the database at the end of each test (like via the TearDown method) and if so how I could achieve this.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818644/nunit-rollback-after-test) and [this](http://xunitpatterns.com/Transaction%20Rollback%20Teardown.html) but they didn't seem to work. I'm guessing this is because I'm not executing any database related operation from the test script itself?

Comment: Are you using transaction ? yiou probably should open a transction at the start of the test then rollback at the end. Other option would be to mock the database writing query to a log and replying with typical expected result  from the DB. I don't think that there is a proper way to do it via web interface unless using a dummy DB

Comment: Both the linked examples used SqlTransaction and so I used it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
      //your code goes here
}
```

Keep in mind, that `auto_increment` counter values will not roll back.

Comment: I did try using the TransactionScope as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating Fakes at your DAL layer so that you are always using the same data for each run and you won't have to worry about having a live connection to a database.  I wrote a bit about the general idea here http://blog.dmbcllc.com/automated-web-application-functional-testing/ if you need more detail.

Comment: I don't really have a DAL per se. This is UI automation after all and I don't have access to the application's source code.