# MySQL Start transaction/rollback doesn't work in integration test

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, nunit, integration-testing

I'm trying to create an integration test for my `User`class using `NUnit`, what I want do is start a `transaction`, update my `MySQL` test db and than rollback.

This is my code, the update is fine but at the and my db remains updated.
Calling my query in `MySQL Workbench` works fine.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class UtenteIntTest
    {
        private User user;
        bool result;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            //Execute query "START TRANSACTION"
            result = false;
        }

        [Test] 
        public void ConstId_IdUser_User()
        {
            user = new User(1);

            if ((user.id == 1) && user.username == "test" && 
                user.name == "test" && user.active == 1 
                && user.mail == "test@test.test")
            {
                result = true;
            }

            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(true));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Update_User_UpdatedUser()
        {
            user = new User(1)
            {
                username = "update",
                password = "update",
                name = "update",
                mail = "update@update.update",
                attivo = 0
            };
            user.Update();
            user = new User(1);

            if ((user.id == 1) && user.username == "update" &&
                user.nominativo == "update" && user.active == 0
                && user.mail == "update@update.update")
            {
                result = true;
            }

            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(true));
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
                //Execute query "ROLLBACK"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check if your database supports transactions.
2. You can use the Transactionscope to test transactions. see. [How do I test database-related code with NUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321180/how-do-i-test-database-related-code-with-nunit)

Comment: I've tried TransactionScope before calling my Update method and it's working fine. Thanks!