# Transact SQL - Get Identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the last or next Identity of a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Some more information in this question - [How Do You Tell What Next Identity Column Will Be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562578/how-do-you-tell-what-next-identity-column-will-be)

And this one - [SQL Identity (autonumber) is Incremented Even with a Transaction Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282451/sql-identity-autonumber-is-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback)

Comment: but I have no scope. I want to get the Identity from a Table that is not in use.

Comment: @bochur1 - sorry dont understand your comment, how can the table not be in use?

Comment: ok. from the first link about I got it:
>>SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('mytable') + IDENT_INCR('mytable') FROM mytable

Comment: FYI: I wouldn't rely on the sequence always being adjacent; gaps can appear if a transaction is rolled back. But for basic snapshot reports it should be OK.

Comment: @bochur1 - hope you noticed that the answer using 'ident_current' goes onto say it doesnt work in all situations.

Answer (score 4):

You can also query the table's current IDENTITY in Management Studio by using:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('YourTable')
```

but that doesn't tell you anything reliably about what the next IDENTITY will be - do **not** attempt to calculate the next IDENTITY yourself! Let SQL Server handle that and grab it using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` once the insert has happened - only that is relevant, really.