# SQL Server - how to ensure identity fields increment correctly even in case of rollback

Tags: sql-server, transactions, rollback, identity-column

In SQL Server, if a transaction involving the inserting of a new row gets rolled back, a number is skipped in the identity field.

For example, if the highest ID in the `Foos` table is 99, then we try to insert a new `Foo` record but roll back, then ID 100 gets 'used up' and the next `Foo` row will be numbered 101.

Is there any way this behaviour can be changed so that identity fields are guaranteed to be sequential?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are after will never work with identity columns.

They are designed to "give out" and forget, by-design so that they don't cause waits or deadlocks etc.  The property allows IDENTITY columns to be used as a sequence within a highly transactional system with no delay or bottlenecks.

To make sure that there are no gaps means that there is NO WAY to implement a 100-insert per second system because there would be a very long queue to figure out if the 1st insert was going to be rolled back.

For the same reason, you normally do not want this behaviour, nor such a number sequence for a high volume table. However, for very infrequent, single-process tables (such as invoice number by a single process monthly), it is acceptable to put a transaction around a `MAX(number)+1` or similar query, e.g.

```
declare @next int
update sequence_for_tbl set @next=next=next+1
.. use @next
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Identity (autonumber) is Incremented Even with a Transaction Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282451/sql-identity-autonumber-is-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback)

Comment: Surely this is not a good idea if you are inserting a lot of data