# why I cannot insert into a MySQL table from Coldfusion8?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, insert

I'm using Coldfusion8 and MySQL and am trying to insert into a table.

However it is not working, no matter if I use a cfquery:

```
<cfquery datasource="dns" result="some">
    INSERT INTO users(iln)
    VALUES("1234567890123")
</cfquery>
<cfdump output="path.txt" var="#some#">
```

or Stored Procedure:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="proc_insert_user" datasource="dns">
   <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="1234567890123" maxlength="13">
</cfstoredproc>
```

with the procedure inside MySQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_insert_user`(IN `user_iln` VARCHAR(13))
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
  COMMENT ''
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO users (iln)
     VALUES(user_iln);
  END
```

If I run the procedure from inside MySQL, it works. From Coldfusion however I cannot access the database. If I set a flag before and after the cfquery/storedProc, both flags show, so I assume there are no errors (I'm not getting any either)

**Question**:
I guess I'm missing some settings in MySQL/Coldfusion. If so, where should I start searching?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**:
When I try to insert a record as above, the table ID keeps increasing, but no new record is shown. So IDs are being created, but I can't see any records. Not sure if this helps.

**EDIT2:**
I have added a results parameter to the Cfquery. If I dump the results, I get:

```
CACHED: false
EXECUTIONTIME: 60
GENERATED_KEY: 42
RECORDCOUNT: 1
SQL: INSERT INTO teilnehmer(iln)
VALUES("1234567891231")
```

Comment: Can you see the result if you do a select statement just after the insert.. SELECT * FROM teilnehmer .. then dump out the result of the select statemet?

Comment: You said this works from inside MySQL.  I'm not too familiar with that, but are you using the same account in your datasource configuration?  Along the lines of what @Jason is asking, it seems like it might be possible that the records are being created, just not visible in the account that you are using within MySQL.

Comment: .. especially since your `result` dump proves the `insert` was successful, and the value assigned id=42. That supports @Barry 's suspicions.

Comment: @Jason: good tip. The records are inserted, they are just not visible. hm. where is the datasource configuration...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me... I had the above INSERT database call inside a **CFtransaction** and there were some statements afterwards, one of which contained an error, which caused all prior transition statements to be reverted. So I guess the records never made it into the database after all with only the id-key increasing as the stored procedure was called.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what should happen. The purpose of the transaction is to ensure *all* statements succeed or fail together. So if even one fails, all of the statements are rolled back. However, auto incrementing id's are usually not reclaimed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537296/sql-server-how-to-ensure-identity-fields-increment-correctly-even-in-case-of-ris-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback