# Identity column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an `Identity` column in a SQL Server table.

When the `Identity` column reaches the value 100, and then if I insert a new record in table, it would be 101.. But in my table it jumps to 10001, I don't know why this happens?

Plz help

Comment: Edit your question to show the `CREATE TABLE...` code for the table in question.  Right-click the table in SQL Server Management Studio, then choose "Script Table As" and "CREATE to", then "New Query Window".

Comment: Which **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using? 2005? 2008? 2008 R2? 2012?

Comment: Did you have any rolled back transactions on that table?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen when a bulk insert is done and rolled back. Assuming your column is defined as `IDENTITY(1,1)`, try this code

```
-- Returns current Identity Value
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('YourTable', NORESEED);
```

This will return a message

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'xxx', current
>   column value 'xxx'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

Now run the following query

```
-- Resets the current Identity value to maximum value
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('YourTable', RESEED, 100);
```

The next insert must pick up from 101

Comment: I am not doing any bulk insert on the table. I insert 425 records in the table, after i insert other records in table, it insert 10385 in the identity coloumn..

Comment: The identity numbers cannot go out of whack without any reason. Check the responses to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074540/sql-server-identity-specification-not-sequential