# Id Identity column value suddenly jumps to 1000, 10000 and etc sometimes in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

Sometime table Identity column value jumps to 60457 from 50489 in SQL Server.

There are some transactions in my project.

I think that this happened due to transactions. I don't know solution of this problem. Please help me. I use Entity Framework in project as ORM.

Comment: ROLLBACK will not revert the identity value to previous stage.

Comment: What is a problem? It should don't matter what value identity column has.

Comment: This is a well known behavior since SQL Server **2012** - and there are many well documented ways you can avoid this (if it *really* is a problem). See that duplicate link for starters

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282451/sql-identity-autonumber-is-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)