# Know identity before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy rows from the table within the table itself. But before inserting I need to modify a varchar column appending the value of identity column to it.
My table structure is:

```
secID docID secName secType secBor
 1     5     sec-1   G        9
 2     5     sec-2   H        12
 3     5     sec-3   G        12
 4     7     sec-4   G        12
 5     7     sec-5   H        9
```

If I want to copy data of say docID 5, currently this runs through a loop one row at a time.

I can write my query as

```
insert into tableA (docID, secName, secType, secBor)
select 8, secName, secType, secBor from tableA where docID = 5
```

But how can I set value of `secName` before hand so that it becomes `sec-<value of secID column>`?

Comment: The onnly way would be to not have secID as an Identity column and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to set these values on insert

Comment: Why not just do `select 8, 'sec-' + CAST([secID] AS varchar(20)), secType, secBor from tableA where docID = 5`

Comment: @RyanWilson, but this will give me secID of previous record. I will need it for the current record. So kind of say, need to know in advance the identity key value getting inserted.

Comment: @CFML_Developer Please see my provided answer.

Comment: Use an after insert trigger may be?

Comment: @SalmanA, yes looks like trigger is the only solution. Because changing table structure is not an option at all because that will involve other unwarranted code changes at other places.

Comment: Since the actual **value** of the identity isn't determined **until the row is actually, physically inserted**, there is **NO** reliable and precise way to know an identity value *before* the insert. Period. Don't waste time on this - you just **CANNOT** know before the insert what that value is going to be.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to *guess* the value of identity column. In your case you could simply create a computed column `secName AS CONCAT('sec-', secID)`. There is no further need to update that column.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1348397664cce8eae5f316d1b497f726)

It is also possible to create an [`AFTER INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) trigger to update the column.

Comment: +1 from me sir. So, I take it that when rolling back a transaction it doesn't reseed the identity column?? That's interesting behavior.

Comment: Yup. Sensible too.

Comment: Why is it sensible? I mean, what harm could befall a table if you cancel all the insertions (ROLLBACK) and reset the identity column to what it was before the ROLLBACK?

Comment: Same way it makes sense not to reseed if a row was deleted.

Comment: I see why if you delete a row that already existed, but in the case of a ROLLBACK, it's as if the insert never took place...

Comment: If anyone is curious like I was about this behavior of the Identity column, this post explains why it doesn't reseed it pretty well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282451/sql-identity-autonumber-is-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment something like:

```
insert into tableA (docID, secName, secType, secBor)
select 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DocID), 
  'Sec -'+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DocID),
  secType, secBor 
from tableA 
where docID = 5
```

Comment: How would this work? He wants the Identity column value appended to sec-, not a ROW_NUMBER() value, If the 6th record in the table had a DocumentId of 5, then ROW_NUMBER() Would return 4 but the identity would be 6. OP's post "I need to modify a varchar column appending the current identity key value in it."

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` would return a sequential number, the ordering is arbitrary in this example. The `IDENTITY` column is the same function just persisted, so if he wants to get the same value at execution time for the `SecId` and `SecName` the only way other than some convoluted trigger would be to generate and insert - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, you can achieve this by using the new [`sequence` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TableAIdentitySeqeunce
START WITH 1  
INCREMENT BY 1 ;  

GO

create table TableA 
(
    secId int default (NEXT VALUE FOR TableAIdentitySeqeunce) not null primary key,
    varcharCol nvarchar(50)
)  

declare @nextId int;
select @nextId = NEXT VALUE FOR TableAIdentitySeqeunce

insert TableA (secId, varcharCol) 
values (@nextId, N'Data #' + cast(@nextId as nvarchar(50)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server does not have `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('Sec - ' + id)` the only simple option I see is to use a trigger.