# How to add identity column with sequential values?

Tags: sql-server

How to add identity column with sequential values? Adding identity column in sql server's existing table does not create sequential number.

Comment: A normal identity column does use sequential values - what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: what do you mean by "not create sequential number"?

Comment: it possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282451/sql-identity-autonumber-is-incremented-even-with-a-transaction-rollback

Comment: Do you mean you want an existing table to have an identity column and you want to have the existing rows to automatically get sequential values?

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @IdentityVal int
select @IdentityVal = MAX(id) from tbl_name
insert into tbl_name(id) select @IdentityVal
```